# Keep an index of fetch asynchronized operation

Tags: javascript

I have to `fetch` photos like this :

```
  for (const imgurl of urls){
        fetch('https:/........url=' + imgurl)
        .then(res => res.blob())
        .then(blob => {
          console.log(blob);
          blobs.push(blob);
        });
```

I would like to keep the order of the `for` loop when i insert the photos into the array.
Which mean, that i am looking for a way to :

1. Add an `index` to the `fetch` *locally*, and read it on the callback.
2. When i get the callback with the `index`, insert the result `blob` to the right `index` in the `blobs` array. (if i got index 4 before 2, put it in 4,  or save and reorganize the array later somehow)

Assuming the array size is unknown and can be 5-9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Promise.all:

```
  const fetches = [];
  for (const imgurl of urls){
    fetches.push(fetch('https:/........url=' + imgurl));
  });
  Promise.all(fetches).then(async results => {
    for (const res of results) {
      const blob = await res.blob();
      console.log(blob);
      blobs.push(blob);
    }
  });
```

like this, not tested. Promise.all guarantees you get the array of results in valid order after all fetches are completed

Comment: how do you know that you keep the order? .all only promise you that it happens when they finished.

Comment: Promise.all keeps the order and so this pattern is often used. "Returned values will be in order of the Promises passed, regardless of completion order." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: thanks, so , your solution works, but it slow things down, because i can't start next thing only when they all finished.. anyway thanks a lot !

Comment: glad to help :) a code after Promise.all starts immediately without waiting, so you can

Comment: something else, the  res.blob will not print a blob, but a promise which i need to get its value somehow

Comment: actually your answer is not correct, you should fix it to return the blob and it requires another .then for it - then you lose the order again :)

Comment: oh thx, fixed with async/await, forgot that blob is async too. in case of another then - we can just use another Promise.all, but then the code would be too complicated :)

Comment: and also :) if you need to track each fetch, not the fact of getting all of them, you can use closures or local variables (simplier). In this case another answer was right (but it still didn't work as expected). You can create counter before the cycle: `let counter = 0;` and (!) create another variable in the cycle before fetch: `const index = counter++;` - don't use `var` here, only let/const. And `blobs[index] = ` instead of `blobs.push` and blobs can still be an array. Problem of the second answer was that the counter's scope was outside the cycle iterations